# Atmosphere Framework Websocket Returns Empty responseBody

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-boot, atmosphere, atmosphere.js

I am using Spring-Boot (embedded container) with Atmosphere Framework based on this [one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-atmosphere) and [two](https://github.com/AndreasKl/springboot-angular-atmosphere-quickstart) sample projects.

I am trying to do a very simple broadcast from one resource, the browser receives the message but the responseBody is empty string "". I debugged through much of Atmosphere code and from what I can tell my JSON message is successfully added to the async write queue but still comes up empty on the browser.

I thought at first it might be that Atmosphere is filtering the message out but debugging shows it isn't.

[image]

**Relevant POM.xml**

```
<spring-boot-starter-web.version>1.3.3.RELEASE</spring-boot-starter-web.version>
<atmosphere-runtime.version>2.2.4</atmosphere-runtime.version>
<atmosphere-javascript.version>2.2.3</atmosphere-javascript.version>
```

**Relevant TRACE Log:**

```
17:39:59.813 TRACE o.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster - /websocket/notifications is about to broadcast Entry{message={"id":1,"msg":"Hello, World"}, type=ALL, future=org.atmosphere.cpr.BroadcasterFuture@15c404ca}
```

**Atmosphere Configuration**

```
package com.hello;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.ApplicationConfig;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.MetaBroadcaster;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AtmosphereConfiguration implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Bean
    public AtmosphereServlet atmosphereServlet() {
        return new AtmosphereServlet();
    }

    @Bean
    public AtmosphereFramework atmosphereFramework() {
        return atmosphereServlet().framework();
    }

    @Bean
    public MetaBroadcaster metaBroadcaster() {
        AtmosphereFramework framework = atmosphereFramework();
        return framework.metaBroadcaster();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        configureAthmosphere(atmosphereServlet(), servletContext);
    }

    private void configureAthmosphere(AtmosphereServlet servlet, ServletContext servletContext) {
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic atmosphereServlet = servletContext.addServlet("atmosphereServlet", servlet);
        atmosphereServlet.setInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.ANNOTATION_PACKAGE, "com.hello");
        atmosphereServlet.setInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.BROADCASTER_CACHE, UUIDBroadcasterCache.class.getName());
        atmosphereServlet.setInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.BROADCASTER_SHARABLE_THREAD_POOLS, "true");
        atmosphereServlet.setInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.BROADCASTER_MESSAGE_PROCESSING_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE, "10");
        atmosphereServlet.setInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.BROADCASTER_ASYNC_WRITE_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE, "10");
        servletContext.addListener(new org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport());
        atmosphereServlet.addMapping("/websocket/*");
        atmosphereServlet.setLoadOnStartup(0);
        atmosphereServlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
    }

}
```

**Atmosphere Resource**

```
package com.hello;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.atmosphere.config.service.Disconnect;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.ManagedService;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.Ready;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@ManagedService(path = NotificationAtmosphereResource.PATH)
public class NotificationAtmosphereResource {

    public static final String PATH = "/websocket/notifications";

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationAtmosphereResource.class);

    public void init(AtmosphereResource resource){
        resource.getResponse().setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    }

    @Ready
    public void onReady(final AtmosphereResource resource) {
        logger.info("Connected {}", resource.uuid());
    }

    @Disconnect
    public void onDisconnect(AtmosphereResourceEvent event) {
        logger.info("Client {} disconnected [{}]", event.getResource().uuid(),
                (event.isCancelled() ? "cancelled" : "closed"));
    }

}
```

Service from which I emit Messages

```
package com.hello;

import org.atmosphere.cpr.MetaBroadcaster;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class NotificationEmitterBean implements NotificationEmitter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationEmitterBean.class);

    @Autowired 
    private MetaBroadcaster metaBroadcaster;

    @Autowired
    private NotificationService notificationService;

    @Autowired
    private JsonMapper jsonMapper;

    @Override
    public void emitForJob(String msg) {
   metaBroadcaster.broadcastTo(NotificationAtmosphereResource.PATH, 
                    jsonMapper.toJson(msg));        
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I didn't try this earlier but the JSON is actually there in the responseBody it just doesn't show in the console when logged with console.dir!!

I don't know why console.dir(response) displays an empty string responseBody though.

```
websocketRequest.onMessage = function(response) {

  // This produces the image in my original question displaying an empty responseJson. Can anyone explain why?
  console.dir(response);

  var message = response.responseBody;
  try {
    var json = atmosphere.util.parseJSON(message);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('This doesn\'t look like a valid JSON: ', message);
    return;
  }      

  console.log(message);

  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
    messages.push(message);
  });
};
```